# Jboss 710 Failed to process phase POST_MODULE

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x

I have been working without any problem and suddenly this happened  :

**JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.deployment.subunit."ear-gestao360.ear"."web-gestao360-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war".POST_MODULE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.subunit."ear-gestao360.ear"."web-gestao360-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war".POST_MODULE: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of subdeployment "web-gestao360-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war" of deployment "ear-gestao360.ear"**

**13:39:59,256 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) {"JBAS014653: Composite operation failed and was rolled back. Steps that failed:" => {"Operation step-2" => {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.subunit.\"ear-gestao360.ear\".\"web-gestao360-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war\".POST_MODULE" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.subunit.\"ear-gestao360.ear\".\"web-gestao360-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war\".POST_MODULE: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of subdeployment \"web-gestao360-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war\" of deployment**

SomeBody have a clue on this ? I really frustrated because I dont know how to solve this issue. thanks so much for helping....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When starting up JBoss AS7 pass in this JVM argument `-Dorg.jboss.as.logging.per-deployment=false` to `standalone.sh` or `domain.sh` . For example:

```
./standalone.sh -Dorg.jboss.as.logging.per-deployment=false
```

This should print more details on the issue. It is most likely a class loading type issue you are seeing.

Comment: thanks so much @CoolBeans. This helped me finding the issue. It was a class loading type issue.